# How to use SSL in gRPC

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

I am completely new in `SSL/TLS` and trying to use this feature in `gRPC` by reading [this](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/). Though I have not found/understood any fruitful from this documentation which pushed me to search workaround from other sources and I have found this [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623793/use-ssl-in-grpc-client-server-communication/41051292#41051292), [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024793/error-in-grpc-with-tls-support), [git issue comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9593#issuecomment-277946137).

- I have built `gRPC` following [this](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/). Explicityl want to say I have not used any extra `cmake command` to build. 100 % followed the same what is written in the mentioned source page.
- I have tried [this github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9593#issuecomment-277946137) to use `ssl tls auth` but I have got the following error when I am trying to execute the `server binary` which seems a common error and also mentioned in the above links.

```bash
E0313 12:18:22.744610595   16503 ssl_transport_security.cc:842] Invalid cert chain file.
E0313 12:18:22.744847251   16503 ssl_security_connector.cc:265] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0313 12:18:22.744951693   16503 server_secure_chttp2.cc:120] {"created":"@1647170302.744899185","description":"Unable to create secure server with credentials of type Ssl","file":"/home/user/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure/server_secure_chttp2.cc","file_line":103}
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- Where/how I have used the `ssl credentials` in `server.cpp`

```cpp
    std::string key;
    std::string cert;
    std::string root;

    read ( "server.crt", cert );
    read ( "server.key", key );
    read ( "ca.crt", root );

    grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair keycert =
    {
        key,
        cert
    };

    grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions sslOps;
    sslOps.pem_root_certs = root;
    sslOps.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back ( keycert );

    grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::SslServerCredentials( sslOps ));
```

- Where/how I have used the `ssl credentials` in `client.cpp`

```cpp
    std::string cert;
    std::string key;
    std::string root;

    read ( "client.crt", cert );
    read ( "client.key", key );
    read ( "ca.crt", root );

    grpc::SslCredentialsOptions opts =
    {
        root,
        key,
        cert
    };

    demo_grpc::C_Request query;
    demo_grpc::S_Response result;

    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(client_address, grpc::SslCredentials ( opts ));
    std::unique_ptr<demo_grpc::AddressBook::Stub> stub = demo_grpc::AddressBook::NewStub(channel);
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    grpc::Status status = stub->GetAddress(&context, query, &result);
```

- I have used the script to generate the certificate, which is also provided in the above [git issue comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9593#issuecomment-277946137)

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  # Generate valid CA
  openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out ca.key 4096
  openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Root CA"

  # Generate valid Server Key/Cert
  openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out server.key 4096
  openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Server/CN=localhost"
  openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

  # Remove passphrase from the Server Key
  openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.key

  # Generate valid Client Key/Cert
  openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out client.key 4096
  openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Client/CN=localhost"
  openssl x509 -passin pass:1234 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

  # Remove passphrase from Client Key
  openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in client.key -out client.key
  ```

Here the writer has told to be careful regarding the following, which is also not clear to me

> The gen-certs.sh script generates valid certificates for grpc. Be carefull changin the OU and CN from the subject. I recommend not use IP addresses in CN because I got some error doing that, is better use hostnames like localhost. Use or set names to the IP that you want to use in /etc/hosts.
> I have just coy paste the `script file` and used it.

- I have placed all the generated file related to `cert/key` in the location of the `binary of the project`
- After building the project, I have just opened two terminal and run the executable separately.
- I am not sure is there any other steps to build or execute the binary
- If you are interested also can see the [github repo here](https://github.com/atifkarim/gRPC_CPP_CMake)

Need suggestions to overcome the error.

> Update. Tried [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24918#issuecomment-741103013) and the problem is gone. Though cannot accept it as here I have used cert, key which is provided by `gRPC`.

Comment: This looks like a cert generation issue. I would recommend to test your code with pre-generated certs first ([gRPC Python Auth example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/auth)), then dig into the details of cert generation. You might also pay extra attention to the goal of using TLS/SSL. If you only want to secure the connection, using server-side cert would suffice. If you also want to validate the client's identity, then you can include the client-side cert.

Comment: @LidiZheng can you kindly provide me any working example (gRPC C++ in Linux system)? I have tried already with the provided `cert ..key file of gRPC` by following [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24918#issuecomment-741103013). No idea why it is not working while I have created certificate by myself. Already attached the sources in the post which i have tried and failed though in those posts they (answer giver) have told that they were successful.